# How to make CKEditor 5 usable without a mouse (for accessibility)?

Tags: accessibility, ckeditor5

I'm using an inline CKEditor 5 in a form that needs to be accessible for the visually impaired. Is there a way to focus buttons of the editor without using a mouse?

Most of the buttons that I've selected for the editor don't have a shortcut associated with them, so tabbing to the button seems to be the only way to press it, but tabbing only focuses the text field, not the buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer: Left Alt + F10 is widely used by visually impaired and can be used to focus the toolbar.